# Expectation of normal distribution with matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, expectation

Let $\boldsymbol{x}\sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, where $\textbf{x}$ is partitioned as $\textbf{x}=(\textbf{x}_1^{T},\textbf{x}_2^{T})$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are partitioned conformably. Let $\boldsymbol{y}=\textbf{x}_1-\textbf{Ax}_2$ for some conformable nonrandom matrix $A$.
Compute E{$\textbf{y}(\textbf{x}_2-\boldsymbol{\mu})^{T}$}.

The solution is E{$\textbf{y}(\textbf{x}_2-\boldsymbol{\mu_2})^{T}$} = $\boldsymbol{\Sigma_{12}}-\boldsymbol{A\Sigma_{22}}$. But I can't figure out why it should be. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\boldsymbol x_2 - \boldsymbol\mu_2$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\boldsymbol \mu$ and $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ are partitioned conformably, we have $\boldsymbol \mu_i = \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_i\}$ and $\boldsymbol \Sigma_{ij} = \mathbb{E}\{(\boldsymbol x_i-\boldsymbol \mu_i)(\boldsymbol x_j-\boldsymbol \mu_j)^T\}$. Multiplying out, we have

$$
\begin{align} 
\boldsymbol \Sigma_{ij}  &= \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_i\boldsymbol x_j^T-\boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol x_j^T - \boldsymbol x_i \boldsymbol \mu_j^T+ \boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol \mu_j^T\} \\&
= \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_i\boldsymbol x_j^T\} - \boldsymbol \mu_i \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_j\}^T - \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_i\}\boldsymbol \mu_j^T + \boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol \mu_j^T \\&
= \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_i\boldsymbol x_j^T\} - \boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol \mu_j^T - \boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol \mu_j^T + \boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol \mu_j^T \\&
= \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_i\boldsymbol x_j^T\} - \boldsymbol \mu_i\boldsymbol \mu_j^T
\end{align}$$

Based this, let us calculate:

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol y (\boldsymbol x_2 - \boldsymbol \mu_2)^T\} & = 
\mathbb{E}\{(\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x_2) (\boldsymbol x_2 - \boldsymbol \mu_2)^T\} \\ &
= \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_1\boldsymbol x_2^T - \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x_2 \boldsymbol x_2^T - \boldsymbol x_1\boldsymbol \mu_2^T + \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol x_2 \boldsymbol \mu_2^T\} 
\\& = \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_1\boldsymbol x_2^T\}
- \boldsymbol A \mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_2\boldsymbol x_2^T\}
- \boldsymbol \mu_1\boldsymbol \mu_2^T + \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol \mu_2\boldsymbol \mu_2^T \\&
= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_1\boldsymbol x_2^T\} - \boldsymbol \mu_1\boldsymbol \mu_2^T}_{\boldsymbol \Sigma_{12}}
-\boldsymbol A \underbrace{\left(\mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol x_2\boldsymbol x_2^T\} - \boldsymbol \mu_2\boldsymbol \mu_2^T\right)}_{\boldsymbol \Sigma_{22}} \\&
= \boldsymbol \Sigma_{12} - \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol \Sigma_{22}
\end{align} 
$$

Let me know if any of the steps is unclear.

Comment: I get it! Muchas gracias!